# Колонки в grid контейнере

Tags: html, css

Можно ли как то убрать последний невидимый блок ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поясните что вы хотите получить. Я не понимаю как модно убрать то чего нет

Comment: @ Alexey Ten нужно чтобы последние 2 блока встали по центру

Comment: Тогда это не грид. Возьмите флексы

Comment: да с флексами то я знаю, а с гридом нельзя типо так ?

Comment: Гриды по определению это строки и столбцы. Наверное можно придумать какой-то хак, но зачем

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: @Георгий Прохоров код сюда пришлите, подберу решение.

Comment: display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: auto;
column-gap: 30px;
row-gap: 30px;
align-items: center;
justify-items: center;